# React - filter out API get requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-router

How do I only fetch/get/retrieve latest 100 records? I'm using React Express Router.

Here is my code so far, but I don't know how to use that limit to 'limit' the records retrieven.

```
router.route("/date/:limit").get((req, res) => {
    let limit = req.params.limit

    Bet.find()
        .then(bets => res.json(bets))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

I'm also wondering if it's possible to only fetch records where the date is equal or after current date.
Data in the database is like this;

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ea7f9f582afe30017785100"
    },
    "date": "April 28th 2020",
    "event": "d vs d"
}
```

And do something like this?

```
router.route("/date/:date").get((req, res) => {
    let date = moment(req.params.date, 'DDMMYYYY')
    let format = date.format('MMMM Do YYYY')
    // format = June 8th 2020
    // how do I do show I only show results after June 8th 2020?
    Bet.find()
        .then(bets => res.json(bets))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

How do I do show I only show results after June 8th 2020 for example?

Comment: you can store in db (or whatever permamnt storage you use) a timestamp for each user and fetch only records after that timestamp, then update timestamp to latest timestamp for example

Comment: yeah, my question is how do I fetch records after that timestamp? what's the command, filter it?

Comment: ok so I figured it out using limit(200) and .sort('_id':-1') but I want to sort after date, any recommendations?

Comment: try using a where clause that selects only entries with timestamp greater than given timestamp https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/